# Developing (.sass) in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, sass

I'm just starting to use VS 2017 and i usually write .sass but turns out VS only recognise .scss files is there a way make VS recognise .sass files??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are (free) extensions available for Visual Studio 2017

One of them is Web Compiler : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

You can install it inside Visual Studio IDE

***Visual Studio Menu option to get extension:***

[image]

***Install:***

[image]

**Update 1: Support to compile ".sass" extension**

Web compiler does not support old ".sass" format.
To compile ".sass", you have to use *gulp-sass*

Below is the procedure how to setup:

1. Enable npm (add package.json )

[image: Add package.json]

2. Add gulp file

[image: Add Gulp file]

3. Modify package.json to install gulp-sass

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

4. Add SASS task

```js
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/" /*Set this to your path accordingly*/
}
paths.scss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.sass"; /*watches sub folders inside wwwroot/css/ */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + "css"));
});
gulp.task('watch-sass', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['sass']);
})
```

5. Setup sass-task and run it

[image: sass-task]

6. Add your .sass file inside the watch folder

[image: .sass file]

7. Whenever you modify your .sass file, .css file will be created

[image: output]
[image]

Comment: this doesn't compile .sass files it complies only .scss files

Comment: @smarty21000 Updated the answer to support .sass , hope this solves the problem ? :)

Comment: Thank you so much that helped a lot.